# docker build returns: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I am trying to buld docker image. I am using Docker Toolbox. If i run `docker build` from bash then it prints the following error:

```
error during connect: Get https://<addr>/v1.37/images/json: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I read that this could be the reason that when certificates are renewed they are [copied to wrong dir](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4547#issue-346309360). I did the fix. I also did `eval $(docker-machine env default)` and it works after running this, however after restarting bash it does not work any more.

However, if i open Kinematic and open docker cli from there it works fine. I want to be able to run docker from bash... How do i solve this error?

Comment: So why you can't execute `eval $(docker-machine env default)` again everytime you enter into bash?

Comment: @atline it is more the question why fresh installation of docker toolbox does not work

Answer (score 0):

Open environment variables page and create all the environment variables listed by running `docker-machine env default` in windows.

The other easier way is to put the command `eval $(docker-machine env default)` in the `~/.bashrc` file.